# Nuxt setContent is not working using tiptap plugin

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm using Tiptap on Nuxt.
Then I create a component separate for the editor.

Then in order to set the content on the editor.
Im using `reference` and `setContent` function.

But I got an error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'matchesNode' of null

I tried to add `no-ssr` and also `forceupdate` on the component,
but still not working

```
setContent (value) {
 let vm = this
 setTimeout( function () {
  if (value) {
   vm.editor.setContent(value, true)
   vm.$forceUpdate()
  }
 }, 3000)
}
```

It should value passed on the function should rendered on the editor.